# Show that $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \cong S_3$ (morphism construction)

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, automorphism-group

I'm curious how we can **construct** a morphism $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow S_3$ and show then that it is an isomorphism.

I know that $(12),(23)$ generate $S_3$ and that $([a]_2,[b]_2)$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ generate $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. But, I don't really see how we can construct it.

If you could give me some ''hints'' I would appreciate it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automorphisms are bijections (of a group into itself) which preserve the order of the elements. Now $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2\cong V_4=\{e,a,b,ab\}$, where *all* the elements have order $2$. Therefore, an automorphism of $V_4$ maps:

- $e$ to $e$;
- $a$ to any among $a,b,ab$;
- $b$ to any between the two elements left available to by previous choice;
- $ab$ to the only element left available by the previous two choices.

Therefore, the elements of $\operatorname{Aut}(V_4)$ actually permutes $3$ objects, just like the elements of $S_3$ do (by definition), and you can map any of the former to the "corresponding" element of $S_3$. Formally, define a bijection $f\colon \{a,b,ab\} \to \{1,2,3\}$. For example, set: $f(a)=2, f(b)=1, f(ab)=3$; then, take $\alpha\in \operatorname{Aut}(V_4)$ defined *e.g.* by (see the bullet points bove): $\alpha(a)=ab, \alpha(b)=b, \alpha(ab)=a$. Now, let the bijection $f$ to come into play:

\begin{alignat}{4}
&\alpha(a)=ab &&\iff f(\alpha(a))=f(ab)=3 &&&\iff f\alpha(f^{-1}(2))=3 &&&&\iff (f\alpha f^{-1})(2)=3 \\
&\alpha(b)=b &&\iff f(\alpha(b))=f(b)=1 &&&\iff f\alpha(f^{-1}(1))=1 &&&&\iff (f\alpha f^{-1})(1)=1 \\
&\alpha(ab)=a &&\iff f(\alpha(ab))=f(a)=2 &&&\iff f\alpha(f^{-1}(3))=2 &&&&\iff (f\alpha f^{-1})(3)=2 \\
\end{alignat}

Therefore, within this framework, the sought morphism maps $\alpha\mapsto (23)$, and similarly for the others elements of $\operatorname{Aut}(V_4)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, @Daniil

Comment: I think I understood the explanation but i have a few questions, please.
1.To what does application $f$ correspond? 
2. Isn't the final result of your example $\alpha \rightarrow (123)$ ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: $f$ is any bijection you can think of, between the two sets. It's arbitrary, but necessary "to construct", as you wished. For 2., no: for the chosen $f$, the given $\alpha$ acts like a permutation which fixes $1$, while $(123)$ doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Any automorphism of the Klein four group must permute the $3$ nonidentity elements.

Comment: I still don't see the construction... I know as well that Aut($\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ has 6 elements. But, i don't really see how it could help me

Comment: All that's really left is to pair permutations of three elements with automorphisms, and show it's a bijective homomorphism.